# CSS table no respect the class values over table

Tags: css, html-table

I have this CSS :

```
table {
margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}   

table th {
color: #38A4FC;
padding-top: 5px;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
width: 200px;
height: 30px;
border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
border-bottom: none;
}

table td {
background-color: #fff;
height: 35px;
border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
padding: 10px;
}

table tr:hover td {
background-color: #eee;
}
```

Also I have this class for other table :

```
.web_table
{
width:90%;
border:0px solid;
}

.web_table_td_left
{
width:50%;
height:30px;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:15px;
color:#000000;
}


.web_table_td_right
{
width:50%;
height:30px;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:15px;
color:#000000;
text-align:center;
}
```

When I use this:

```
<table class="web_table"><tr><td class="web_table_tf_left"></td><td class="web_table_tf_right"></td></tr></table>
```

The table use the values of "table" in CSS and no the class, I don't know whats bad in this code, I think if you use one class must to take the values of class and no the others I suppose.

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're having? What did you expect it to do, and what is it doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how many man hours have been lost to typos. I've probably lost a year at this point. :)

Your CSS has rules for `.web_table_td_right` but your HTML has classes named `web_table_tf_right`. **td** vs **tf**.

http://jsfiddle.net/MRrYs/

Comment: It´s the same man , i put that bad when i writte but the result it´s the same , the problem it´s with override table css over class or id

Comment: Did you look at the fiddle? I set the text to have different colors and it's working fine. "What exactly is the issue you're having? What did you expect it to do, and what is it doing wrong? –  @badAdviceGuy 1 hour ago "